# Can't send text to java Upload file window when remote desktop minimized

Tags: java, windows, selenium, jenkins, autoit

I'm writing an automated test for a web application with Java + Selenium.

In that test I need to upload a certificate to login on the web application.
For uploading the file I use an AutoIt script like this:

```
Local $hWnd = WinWaitActive("Upload file")
WinActivate($hWnd)
ControlSend ($hWnd, "", "", "C:\my_cert.p12")
Sleep(5000)
Send("{ENTER}")
Exit
```

I run this script from Java test and it works perfect on my PC (Windows 10).

When I run my Java test from Jenkins on a remote PC (Windows 7) it works fine when I connected on that PC with remote desktop connection manager, and looking how it works.

**BUT** when I minimize the remote desktop manager (or shut it down) and run the test again it gets stuck the moment the AutoIt script needs to insert the file path to the upload window. It looks like the script didn't see the upload window and continues to wait for it.

I've tried to use java.awt.Robot, but it gave the same result.

If it helps: AutoIt detects that the upload file window has a class called SunAwtDialog.